# How to remove unnecessary object names in String of JSONArray?

Tags: java, json, string, logic

I have JSONArray in String format as follows :

```
{
    "productsList": [{
            "map": {
                "productSubcategory": "Levensverzekering",
                "nameFirstInsured": "Akkerman"
            }
        },
        {
            "map": {
                "productSubcategory": "Lineair dalend",
                "nameFirstInsured": "Akkerman"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert this String as follows :

```
{
    "productsList": [{

            "productSubcategory": "Levensverzekering",
            "nameFirstInsured": "Akkerman"

        },
        {

            "productSubcategory": "Lineair dalend",
            "nameFirstInsured": "Akkerman"

        }
    ]
}
```

I have converted JSONArray to String so need operation as on the String on provided String in JSON format.
How I can change the String as required? What should I put in jsonString.replaceAll("","") function?

Comment: No, you should not be doing this on strings to begin with. Work on the actual object, get that into the form you want it to be - and then encode it as JSON.

Comment: JsonArray actually doesn't contain that "map" word but when I apply it the Gson, it automatically takes it as various different objects. That's why I need  operation on String itself please..

Comment: No clue what you are trying to say here. A key does not magically appear when an object is converted to JSON - that object would have had to have that key to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, you have to do something like this.

OUTPUT IS:

```
{  
   "productsList":[  
      {  
         "productSubcategory":"Levensverzekering",
         "nameFirstInsured":"Akkerman"
      },
      {  
         "productSubcategory":"Lineair dalend",
         "nameFirstInsured":"Akkerman"
      }
   ]
}



import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;


public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject newObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("test.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("productsList");
            JSONArray newArr = new JSONArray();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size();i++){
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                JSONObject a = (JSONObject) object.get("map");
                newArr.add(a);
            }
            newObj.put("productsList", newArr);
            System.out.println(newObj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```